# WIX Bootstrap List Installed Packages Individually in Programs list

Tags: wix

I have a bootstrap wix install with about 6 installers. after they are installed only the "full" bootstrap installer is listed in programs in windows. I ideally need each msi that was installed listed. Is this possible and if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each package element, set the attribute [Visible](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/msipackage.html)="yes".

Comment: ah... So easy. Completely missed that. Thanks