# Wix Burn: How to stop Bootstrapper from installing itself

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, burn, wix3.7

I believe this question might have been asked before me, but somehow, I'm not finding some appropriate answer.

I may have to write my own managed bootstrapper. But up-till now, in the examples I got, the bootstrapper  is installing itself as well and appearing in Add-Remove programs instead of my product.

**Question:** Can we make bootstrapper to only install our products and pre-requisite applications and not to install itself?

Regards

Comment: For the minor point of "instead of my product", see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20961514/2226988).

Comment: @TomBlodget, Yes, I'm aware of that, but that won't stop the bootstrapper to install itself. Instead all of my apps and pre-reqs would be visible in Add-Remove along with boostrapper.

Comment: Bob Arnson [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21000619/2226988) your main question. His linked article explains it quite well. 

That feature was a surprise to me, too. But, consider shifting focus from how to eliminate it to how to embrace it, particularly if a user might install more than product (yours or anyone's) that uses Burn's package management features.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Burn is not a "fire and forget" bootstrapper. See http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2012/6/25/b-is-for-bundle-and-thats-good-enough-for-me and http://www.joyofsetup.com/2013/07/05/burn-zero-one-or-n/.