# How to use an exitcode of an executable in an installcondition of a package in WIX

Tags: wix, bootstrapper

I am creating a bundle with several packages. One of these packages needs to be installed if the exit code of an executable has a certain value.

Is it possible to set the install condition of a package based on the exit code of an executable?

Answer (score 1):

Burn only runs packages after it's already planned what to do with all of them. So no, you can't run an ExePackage and use its exit code to change the plan for another package. If you write a custom bootstrapper application, you could run an .exe, capture its exit code, and use it in the plan.

Answer (score -1):

You may be able to use Burn Bootstrapper - part of the WIX toolkit: 
[Wix Burn: How to stop Bootstrapper from installing itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995779/wix-burn-how-to-stop-bootstrapper-from-installing-itself)

Comment: I am using Burn, but how do I link the exitcode of an executable to the installcondition of a package?